# How to re-render after a click Vue

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vue-component

I have a table component that is rendered when a node on my diagram is selected. In my template for the component that is rendering the table I have this:

```
<div v-if="this.nodeName != ''" class="flex">
    <table-details :title="tableName" :cardListData="valuesCardData"/>
  </div>
```

the problem is once the name is clicked the nodeName is no longer an empty string so it wont render again with the new data. Here is how I am getting the name + the API call to back end.

```
 data() {
      return {
          nodeName: '',
          tableName: null,
   }
}
    getNodeClicked() {
        window.addEventListener('sankey_node_clicked', (e) => { (this.nodeName = e.detail.name) })
      },
      async getTableData() {
        const nodeData = this.dateRange
        ? await get('nodeData', {
            dateStart: this.dateRange[0],
            dateEnd: this.dateRange[1],
            nodeName: this.nodeName
        }) : await get('nodeData', {
            nodeName: this.nodeName
          });
          console.log(nodeData)
        this.valuesCardData.push(nodeData);
      },  
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the `:key` attribute on your component to force the re-rendering.

There's a whole article written by Michael Thiessen about re-rendering:

https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/

The only thing you have to do is to put the key on your `table-details` (key should (or need to ?) be put on components, not native HTML elements), and decide what you want to use as a key (could be an id, or your node name, or a simple number you increment when you press a button)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work perfectly, It's all about how `nodeName` value is getting update.

Here is the working demo, Please have a look. It will help you in finding the root cause.

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  props: ['childmsg'],
  template: '<div>{{ childmsg }}</div>'
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    nodeName: 'alpha'
  },
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.nodeName = 'beta';
    }, 5000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-if="nodeName != ''">
    <child :childmsg="nodeName">
    </child>
  </div>
</div>
```